# How do I repeat textures without stretching in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, texture-mapping

No matter what I do, my textures seem to be getting stretched / scaled to the size of the mesh I am applying them to. I've read a lot of answers to this question, none of the solutions seem to have fixed things for me so I'm posting a new one. Just a bit of info,

- My textures are all 64x64 pixels
- I am preloading all my textures
- I am using the Web GL renderer

Here is my code

```
makeTestObject:function()
{
    var scope = this,
        tileGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(TILE_SIZE , TILE_HEIGHT , TILE_SIZE),
        texture = new THREE.Texture(preloadedImageObject),
        textureMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map:texture}),
        tile = new THREE.Mesh(tileGeometry , new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(
        [
            textureMaterial, // +x
            textureMaterial, // -x
            textureMaterial, // +y
            textureMaterial, // -y
            textureMaterial, // +z
            textureMaterial // -z
        ]));

    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

    tile.position.y = BASE_HEIGHT * 2;
    tile.castShadow = true;
    tile.receiveShadow = true;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    scope.scene.add(tile);
}
```

If I do `texture.repeat.set(x , x)` and set `x` to any kind of value, the texture just seems to disappear and I'm left with a flat colour.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what are the dimensions of your texture? I think they have to be a power of 2, something like 512x512 or 1024x1024 or 512x256 (sorry, I just read your post again and saw your images are 64x64)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so for a standard box geometry (square or rectangular) the solution is this;

```
makeTestObject:function()
{
    var scope = this,
        tileGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(TILE_SIZE , TILE_HEIGHT , TILE_SIZE),
        texture = new THREE.Texture(preloadedImageObject),
        textureMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map:texture}),
        tile = new THREE.Mesh(tileGeometry , new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(
        [
            textureMaterial, // +x
            textureMaterial, // -x
            textureMaterial, // +y
            textureMaterial, // -y
            textureMaterial, // +z
            textureMaterial // -z
        ]));

    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    tile.geometry.computeBoundingBox();

    var max = tile.geometry.boundingBox.max;
    var min = tile.geometry.boundingBox.min;
    var height = max.y - min.y;
    var width = max.x - min.x;

    texture.repeat.set(width / TEXTURE_SIZE , height / TEXTURE_SIZE);

    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    scope.scene.add(tile);
}
```

The key is setting the ratios correctly for the repetition of the texture. You also might want to create a new material for each face rather than reference the same material object over and over.